Postgresql - Pgbouncer Connection and Query Performance Problem
We are using prepared transactions in PostgreSQL.
We use pgbouncer as our pooling software. From time to time, I encountered connection issues in my database sessions, and to resolve them, I had to restart pgbouncer.
While the pool_mode parameter in pgbouncer was set to session, I changed it to transaction, and the connection issue was resolved.
However, I am now experiencing significant slowdowns in my queries. I attribute this to two parameters in my PostgreSQL clusters and three parameters in pgbouncer.
Firstly, on my server, I have 15 PostgreSQL clusters, and the values of these two parameters in the postgresql.conf file of each cluster seem very high:
max_connection = 4096
max_prepared_transaction = 4096

These two parameters are set to 4096 in all 15 clusters.
Do these values seem too high, and could they be causing my queries to run slowly?
On the other hand, the values I find high in pgbouncer are:
max_db_connections = 8192
default_pool_size = 4096
max_client_conn = 2048

Could these high values be causing excessive load on pgbouncer?
I have actively 15,000 customers on my server, and there is an average data flow of 5 million daily (including updates). What should be the value of these parameters? Especially, what should I pay attention to when setting pgbouncer parameters?
I changed the specified three parameters in pgbouncer to the following values;
max_db_connections = 500
default_pool_size = 300
max_client_conn = 500

Currently, it seems like my query performance has improved, but what should I do to permanently solve this? What other parameters should I pay attention to besides these?

prepared transactions, why do you need this? This is slow by design. Your connection configuration is a little odd, the number of connections per cluster is very high and with 15 clusters it's imho out of control. We have a setup for about 5 million customers and a 400 million transactions per day, max_connection = 500. Most of the time the number of active (!) connections is below 20. However, prepared transactions is turned off, that was a massive performance killer and didn't add any value for us.

The software department is using prepared transactions, and if I turn off this parameter, they encounter errors in prepared transactions. If having set these two parameters too high is causing my queries to slow down, then I can reduce both parameters to 500.

On the other hand, when I lowered the max_client_connection parameter to 500 in the pgbouncer config file, I encountered the following error in one of my clusters and had to increase it again: "no more connections allowed (max_client_conn)." This is probably due to prepared transactions causing too many sessions to be opened. What do you suggest? Should I try reducing the max_connection and max_prepared_transactions parameters to a minimum of 500?

When I checked the sessions in my database using the pg_stat_activity view during periods of slow query performance, I noticed a significant number of LWLocks. What could be causing this? From the articles I've read, LWLocks don't seem to pose a major problem. However, in the database where slowness occurs, there were constantly 60-70 queries of the LWLock type, sometimes even reaching up to 80. Do you have any ideas about this?

The software department is using prepared transactions, I understand, but the question is "why?". What is the functional benefit for your software, what problem does it solve? We told the Java developers to stop using this, they did and everything runs much faster. They never needed prepared transactions, they used it just because that's what they always did.

I will discuss this issue with our software department because I don't know why they are using it, they probably use it in the operations they frequently do. I will get back to you after learning.
Connection management is probably not done correctly, and I think these operations are causing locks in the database.

The reason we use prepared_transaction is for the commit and rollback structure, having the option to rollback an operation. Most of our databases contain raw data in tables, so enabling rollback is important for our system. What can we use instead of this? As an alternative, what structure have you transitioned to?

For this you need a transaction, not a prepared transaction. These are different things. From the manual: PREPARE TRANSACTION is not intended for use in applications or interactive sessions. Its purpose is to allow an external transaction manager to perform atomic global transactions across multiple databases or other transactional resources. Unless you're writing a transaction manager, you probably shouldn't be using PREPARE TRANSACTION.. From what you're writing over here, you just need BEGIN TRANSACTION; and COMMIT; or ROLLBACK;.
